# AndroidStudio error: Access is denied?

Tags: filenotfoundexception

If I create a new project from scratch or open one of my previous projects I get:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\Terry.AndroidStudio2.2\system\android-palette\v1\layout_palette.xml
>   (Access is denied).

I didn't have any problems previously and now all of a sudden I get this error.

I had no problem opening this file using the IDE so I don't understand why it has a problem opening it.

Does anyone have any suggestions?
I'm using version 2.2.3.

Here is the sequence of events:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Terry\.AndroidStudio2.2\system\android-palette\v1\layout_palette.xml (Access is denied)
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Terry\.AndroidStudio2.2\system\android-palette\v1\layout_palette.xml (Access is denied)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.palette.NlPaletteModel.loadPalette(NlPaletteModel.java:82)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.palette.NlPaletteModel.getPalette(NlPaletteModel.java:60)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.palette.NlPalettePanel.checkForNewMissingDependencies(NlPalettePanel.java:542)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.palette.NlPalettePanel.setDesignSurface(NlPalettePanel.java:195)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.palette.NlPalettePanel.<init>(NlPalettePanel.java:140)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.editor.NlPaletteManager.createContent(NlPaletteManager.java:88)
    at com.intellij.designer.LightToolWindowManager$4.run(LightToolWindowManager.java:261)
    at com.intellij.designer.LightToolWindowManager$4.run(LightToolWindowManager.java:258)
    at com.intellij.designer.LightToolWindowManager.bind(LightToolWindowManager.java:208)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.editor.NlPreviewForm.lambda$attachPalette$178(NlPreviewForm.java:336)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.runWhenSmart(DumbServiceImpl.java:163)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.editor.NlPreviewForm.attachPalette(NlPreviewForm.java:332)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.editor.NlPreviewForm.setActiveModel(NlPreviewForm.java:326)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.editor.NlPreviewForm$Pending.run(NlPreviewForm.java:264)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:345)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:329)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:658)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Terry\.AndroidStudio2.2\system\android-palette\v1\layout_palette.xml (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.palette.NlPaletteModel.copyPredefinedPalette(NlPaletteModel.java:99)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.palette.NlPaletteModel.loadPalette(NlPaletteModel.java:74)
    ... 32 more
```

Answer (score 1):

It was a simple fix.  I made the files **layout_palette.xml** and **menu_palette.xml**  writeable and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me all the directories under the /.AndriodStudio were hidden and read-only mode. I changed the permission and after that it is start working.